# hibernate-4 jboss-4 configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

Trying to configure a simple app and deploy to jboss 4.0.5 but i get
i have also change the jdbc driver and tested both jdbc 3 and jdbc4 but the same problem occurs

```
  java.sql.SQLException: ERROR:  SET AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF is no longer supported

        at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:131)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Connection.ExecSQL(AbstractJdbc1Connection.java:482)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Connection.ExecSQL(AbstractJdbc1Connection.java:461)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Connection.setAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc1Connection.java:957)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
        at testingmodel2.Example1Servlet.processRequest(Example1Servlet.java:30)
        at testingmodel2.Example1Servlet.doGet(Example1Servlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
14:05:46,315 ERROR [[Example1Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Example1Servlet threw exception
org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
        at testingmodel2.Example1Servlet.processRequest(Example1Servlet.java:30)
        at testingmodel2.Example1Servlet.doGet(Example1Servlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR:  SET AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF is no longer supported

        at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:131)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Connection.ExecSQL(AbstractJdbc1Connection.java:482)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Connection.ExecSQL(AbstractJdbc1Connection.java:461)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Connection.setAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc1Connection.java:957)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:63)
        ... 24 more
```

also my postgres-ds.xml is

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>PostgresDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dvdrental</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
    <password>*******</password>
        <!-- sql to call when connection is created.  Can be anything, select 1 is valid for PostgreSQL
        <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
        -->

        <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool.  Can be anything, select 1 is valid for PostgreSQL
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        -->

      <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
      <!--<metadata>
         <type-mapping>PostgreSQL 7.2</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
      -->
  </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

i am noob so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a JDBC driver that is using **SET AUTOCOMMIT**, you need to update to a 7.4-compatible or higher driver.  If you have an application that is using **SET AUTOCOMMIT**, it's broken in itself, because only the driver should be messing with that.

Comment: i have 9.3-1102 JDBC 3 driver and i am not using set autocommit.. so what is the problem?

Comment: you are right Jboss has PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 7.3.4 JDBC3 jdbc driver build 113 ! now the question is how do i install jdbc in jboss 4 ?

Comment: Thanks the problem was that jboss used the version 7.3.4 jdbc3 driver .